# What is the difference between the two following arrows $\mapsto$ and $\to$?

Tags: notation

Can someone please define the meaning of the two following arrows and tell me what the difference is between them? When would you use one or the other?

$\mapsto$ and $\to$

Thank you so much!

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $f: x \mapsto x^2$.

Comment: It's just convenience

Answer (score 1):

It's a notational convention to use $\to$ to denote a mapping of objects and $\mapsto$ a mapping of elements.

e.g. if $f$ is the map on the real line that sends a real number $x$ to $x + 1$ then we may denote this as
$$
f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R,\; x \mapsto x + 1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer was more or less already given by @Randall in the comment section.
The first arrow is called *mapsto* and as its name suggests it means that the object to its left is mapped to the object on its right side.

Thus $x \mapsto x^2$ means that any inserted value for $x$ will get mapped to its squared value.

The second arrow typically is used to describe the relationship between the spaces a function operates on, so $f \colon \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y} $ means that any value inserted into $f$ stemming from the space $\mathcal{X}$ will be mapped by some mechanism (cf. $\mapsto$) into the space $\mathcal{Y}$.

Comment: This is very helpful! I just have one followup question: How would I read each of these symbols outloud.

Comment: I suppose just like their TeX symbols: _mapso_ for $\mapsto$ and _to_ for $\to$.
So for $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto x^2$ you could say "$f$ is a function that goes from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ where each element is mapped to its squared value."
Note that you can also say that $f$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clear distinction when it comes to functions. For instance,
$$\exp: {\Bbb R} \rightarrow {\Bbb R}_{>0}: x\mapsto e^x.$$.